# Array Find does not return the correct answer in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, find

I have list of data with different data as follows

```
[0: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Allocate", pairStatus: 1, …}
 1: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission", pairStatus: 1, …}
 2: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Aggregate", pairStatus: 1, …}
 3: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1, …}
 4: {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1, …}]

 var getAutoRow;
 getAutoRow = this.latlist.find(fetch => fetch.lat== lat);
```

I need output as follows - when i select specify **lat** from data list

```
[0: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission"}]
```

I can't pass title. Could you please help me to find specify **lat** data using lat and index

Comment: The simplest solution: `getAutoRow = [getAutoRow]`

Comment: what you need an array or object?

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski Did not get you. How to pass index dynamically

Comment: @Bansi29 I need array

Comment: @Nishanth then you pass the filter like `const getAutoRow = this.latlist.filter(fetch => fetch.lat == lat);`

Comment: @Bansi29 When i use filter i am not getting auto suggestion list in datalist

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` array method to filter an array matching a specific condition. It returns a new Array matching your condition.

Note that you should always use `===` when comparing values in JS.

```js
let data= [{lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Allocate", pairStatus: 1},
 {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission", pairStatus: 1},
  {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Aggregate", pairStatus: 1},
  {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1},
 {lat: "37.7745586", lng: "-121.9610328", title: "Ship", pairStatus: 1}];
 //console.log(data)
 let lat = '37.7745586';
 const getAutoRow = data.filter(fetch => fetch.lat === lat);
  console.log(getAutoRow)
```

** Update :

This how you should implement in Angular  :

in `component.html` :

```
 <input type="text" list="latList" name="latitude" [(ngModel)]='result' (change)="getValues(result)" />
     <datalist id="latList">
       <select>
        <option *ngFor="let product of data" [value]="product.lat"></option>
       </select>
     </datalist>
<input type="button" id="sub" (click)="getResult()" value="sub"/>
```

In `component.ts` file write below method when button is clicked :

```
getResult(){

   this.selectedLat = this.data.filter((item)=>{
        return item.lat === this.result
   })

  }
```

Here is the working demo : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gymmy1)

Comment: we will select lat number from auto suggestion text box so not able to use filter

Comment: @Nishanth can you elaborate how you are getting the value of `lat` ??

Comment: I will be selecting from auto suggestion text box where there will be list of values

Comment: you can write `change` event on auto select box. if possible add html code

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/TE6dk/2 verify this. when i select "John Snow" it always return first id. instead it should return specify selected id @programoholic

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/TE6dk/2

Comment: @Nishanth it's JQuery not angular.

Comment: Yes. That's the required functionality in angular

Comment: @programholic I have tried the same but it does not return the data exactly. by selecting the specify lat number i should return entire row as [0: {lat: "37.829998", lng: "-122.003152", title: "Commission"}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210649/discussion-between-programoholic-and-nishanth).